# I have a Schwinn Skyliner bicycle for my wife

Tags: mountain-bike

I need to replace a quick release skewer that came out of the front wheel of the bike. What specific Skewer do I need? How long is the skewer and how thick is the rod of the skewer?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have the old skewer?

Comment: No I do not. My wife noticed that the wheel did not look sturdy. After I check it out, I notice that the skewer was gone. Thank you for answering my question and I hope you have a solution.

Comment: Eek!!! I'm glad you still have a wife. Unsecured front wheels can go very badly.